# export PATH doesn't work correctly

Tags: bash, java, android, environment-variables

I have a problem with `$PATH` export. The only place I found where I modify `$PATH` is `/etc/environment`:

```
ANDROID_HOME="/opt/ADT/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130522/sdk"
PROJECT_HOME="/home/tomaszchabinka/Dokumenty/tempFile/android_stb"
PATH="/opt/gradle-1.10/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

But when I type in terminal `echo $PATH` it returns:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin
```

I don't have `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin` directory so I don't understand why my `$PATH` export doesn't works and where does `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin` come from.

Also `$ANDROID_HOME` and `$PROJECT_HOME` exports correctly; only $PATH export doesn't work.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You should be placing those types of exports in $HOME/.bashrc or $HOME/.zshrc or whichever shell dotfile corresponds to your environment. If this needs to propagate to new user accounts, place it in /etc/skel/ in the appropriate dotfile.

Comment: I've tried this earlier (with .bashrc and with .profile) and also didn't work

Answer (score 3):

There are a few places where you can define `$PATH`:

- `/etc/environment` is a plain text file (not a script) that affects all users
- `~/.pam_environment` - the same thing but user-specific

`bash` also executes some scripts which can be used for modifying `$PATH`:

- `~/.profile` is executed for a login shell sessions (don't ask me what it means :)
- `~/.bashrc` is executed for non login interactive shell sessions
- `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bash.bashrc` are system wide alternatives for `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc`

I read somewhere that `/etc/environment` is a recommended place for defining your `$PATH`.
So I usually use it. But your path is probably modified in one of the other places.

BTW, when you execute a command with `sudo`, I think it normally uses `root` user's `$PATH` (and not the `$PATH` of your unprivileged user account). 
So, `~/.pam_environment`, `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` in `/root` directory may also play a role.

Answer (score -2):

Put this in ~/.bashrc:

`PATH="${PATH}:/opt/gradle-1.10/bin"`

Comment: Welcome to the site and thank you for your input. You answer could be improved by adding a bit more, for example; what the expected result is, if it worked for you and such like.